# Full screen background image size for android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-image

What pixel size should I draw images to be set on background for android wear watches?

My Moto 360 seems to have 240dp in hdpi. I would like to know about other watches.

Comment: Check this post: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+WaynePiekarski/posts/YXbZMLhEJ2L

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the image I posted in https://plus.google.com/+WaynePiekarski/posts/YXbZMLhEJ2L

This has the resolution, DPI, and densityDpi values for every Android Wear watch as of July 2015.

Using a 320x320 image for a watch face or activity background will work, but in the future you will need to deal with new screen sizes.

Note that for notification card backgrounds, the image needs to be actually 640x400 (for parallax) and 400x400 for no parallax. See the documentation for more details on this: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#AddWearableFeatures

[image: Screen details of all Android Wear devices from July 2015]

Answer (score 6):

At the moment using a 320x320 bitmap should cover all the bases for you.

Here are details:

- Asus Zen Watch: 320x320 pixels, density 1.75, 182dpx182dp
- Gear Live: 320x320 pixels, density 1.75, 182dpx182dp
- LG G Watch: 280x280 pixels, density 1.5, 186dpx186dp
- LG G Watch R: 320x320 pixels, density 1.5, 213dpx213dp
- LG Urbane: 320x320pixels, density 1.5 213dpx213dp
- Moto 360: 320x290 pixels, density 1.33, 240x217dp
- Sony Smartwatch: 320x320 pixels, density 1.75, 182dpx182dp

You might consider optimizing for the LG G Watch and using smaller bitmap, but it doesn't seem like worth the time.

Comment: can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698943/android-wear-os-watch-face-support-different-screen-sizes